# Spring Security 4.1 upgrade - HttpServletRequest isUserInRole returning false

Tags: spring, spring-security

After login successfully, isUserInRole method of HttpServletRequest class is returning false. It was returning true prior to Spring Security version upgrade to 4.1.3.

spring-security-core-4.1.3, spring-security-web-4.1.3, and spring-security-config-4.1.3 jars are present in the class-path

Spring-Security.xml

```
 ...
<spring:bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
</spring:bean>

<spring:bean id="authenticatedVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>

<spring:bean id="webExpressionVoter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter" />

<spring:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
      <spring:constructor-arg>
       <spring:list>
            <spring:ref bean="roleVoter"/>
            <spring:ref bean="authenticatedVoter"/>
            <spring:ref bean="webExpressionVoter"/>
        </spring:list>
  </spring:constructor-arg>
</spring:bean>

<security:http access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" use-expressions="true">

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="hasAuthority('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')"/>

    <security:form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
        username-parameter="j_username"
        password-parameter="j_password"
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
        authentication-failure-url="/accessDenied.jsp" />

    <security:logout invalidate-session="true"  delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>

    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>

</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="secAuthManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="securityProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<spring:bean id="securityProvider" class="com.SecurityProvider"/>

...
```

class SecurityProvider

```
    public class SecurityProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

...

                List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = ...                 

return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, grantedAuthorities);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
            return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
        }
    }
```

If I replaces 4.1.3 security jars with 3.2.9 version and remove `<security:csrf disabled="true"/>` from Spring-Security.xml then it works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved after adding `ROLE_` prefix for each `GrantedAuthority` in `List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities`.